# How to style sister or brother div

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to style sister div but not by using this id #rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form

Example

`div + #rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form { padding:10px; font-size:18px; }`

```
<div>Arrival Date: 19/09/2013</div>
<div>Departure Date: 21/09/2013</div>
<div>Nights: 2</div>
<form id="rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form"></form>
```

[image]

Solution:

```
div ~ #rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: `sister or brother` == `parent and child`

Comment: Can you be more specific please? You say you are trying to style the `div`s that are next to each other, but which ones do you want to style and how? There are selectors that can probably help you here (such as `+`) but it's difficult to give specific help without knowing exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: if you're trying to target the `div`s, its not working. http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/yWXuu/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS previous sibling selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792).

Comment: just a comment on your "solution" section in your post. `id's` are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the an element next to another element using the plus sign.

E.g.

```
div + div { padding: 10px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i figure out

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper for all the form items as follows

```
<div class="form-item-wrapper>
    <div class="form-item form-type-item">
    <div class="form-item form-type-item">
</div>
```

and then the CSS is :

```
<style>
    .form-item-wrapper > div{
        padding: 10px  
    }
</style>
```

Here is a good article http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help

I can't create any wrapper, the only way i have using css, where i want to style pre div by using this id #rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to select all the `div`s that come prior to your form (#rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form)?

If you are not allowed to change the DOM, [you can't achieve that via pure CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792), but if you're allowed to use JQuery, then its pretty simple.

```
$("#rooms-booking-manager-change-search-form").prevAll('div').css('background-color','red');
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/yWXuu/1/)